# Show $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} > 0$ and $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \le 1$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$. Let $\varphi = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$.

> Show that $\varphi > 0, \nu$-a.e. and if $\nu(A) \le \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$ then $\varphi \le 1, \nu$-a.e.

Now I know that $\nu(A) = \int_A \varphi d\mu(x)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$. If there was a $C \in \mathcal A$ with $\nu(C)>0$ and $\varphi|_C = 0$, then $\nu(\Omega) = \int_{\Omega \setminus C}\varphi d\mu (x) = \nu(\Omega \setminus C)$. Which is a contradiction. Is that correct?

How can I show the second statement?

Comment: If $\nu$ is not absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$ then expression for $\nu(A)$ is not correct. Try to use definition of derivative of measure wrt other measure.

Comment: @Mayuresh I thought that expression _is_ the definition.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be $\nu(A) \le \mu(A)$. After all, if $\nu = 2\mu$, then obviously $\mu \le \nu$, but $\phi = 2$. Either you have the inequality reversed, or it should be $\phi = \frac {d\mu}{d\nu}$. Otherwise the result is false.

Comment: @Paul Yes, indeed.

Comment: Second statement: $\int_A \phi d\mu \leq \mu(A)$. Take $A=\{\phi >1\}$. You can conclude that $\mu (A) =0$ hence $\nu (A) =0$.